# Raphael JS: Cannot mask objects. Alternative?

Tags: html, canvas, svg, raphael

I thought HTML5's SVG would do this. So I played around with Raphael JS.

What I want is akin to having a picture frame, masking an underlying picture. It needs to be scalable.

So I want to define the 'picture frame' with svg or similar. Then define the mask area. Then finally define the picture underneath in terms of objects.

Lastly, I will want to animate the objects that I consider the picture.

What would be a similar way to do this than using Raphael? I've discovered that I cannot define a mask in Raphael which rules using that out. I only need it to work in Firefox and Chrome, and the simpler the library the better. In total I only expect to draw around 50 elements, so a method that suits that? (I presume SVG is a better choice than 2d Canvas). I don't need mouse interaction with the objects.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I need a non-rectangular mask

Comment: Both SVG and Canvas can do clipping using any non-rectangular path.

Answer (score 4):

[SVG can do this](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Clipping_and_Masking), but Raphaël doesn't support masks (probably some VML restriction). Simple rectangular clipping is supported however, see the [Raphaël documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr) (you want `clip-rect`, which is Raphaël's abstraction/limited-version of svg's `clip-path`).

A few examples of clipping and masking in SVG can be found [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/masking/) and [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/clippath/).

Answer (score 3):

Canvas can do what you’re asking.

Just put 2 canvas’ on top of each other.  The bottom canvas is the frame.   The top canvas (which is smaller than the frame) is the picture.  Then you can animate all you want on the picture.  If your animation is simple, you might not even need a canvas library to keep track of your drawn elements.  Excellent performance too since you’re not having the DOM track your elements as with SVG.

BTW, you could do the same with 1 canvas drawn on top of an SVG frame if you already have your frame drawn in SVG.  Actually, you could even use an image for the frame if you wanted.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9Tj3s/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #container{
      position:relative;
      border:1px solid green;
      width:1380px;
      height:1315px;
    }
    #frame{
      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      border:1px solid red;
    }
    #picture{
      position:absolute;
      top:66px;
      left:67px;
      border:1px solid blue;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var frame=document.getElementById("frame");
        var ctxFrame=frame.getContext("2d");
        var picture=document.getElementById("picture");
        var ctxPicture=picture.getContext("2d");

        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
            ctxFrame.drawImage(this,0,0,frame.width,frame.height);
        } 
        img.src="http://www.themezoom-neuroeconomics.com/images/5/5e/Golden-frame.jpg";

        var dx= 4;
        var dy=4;
        var y=150;
        var x=10;
        function draw(){
            ctxPicture.clearRect(0,0,243,182);
            ctxPicture.beginPath();
            ctxPicture.fillStyle="#0000ff";
            ctxPicture.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
            ctxPicture.closePath();
            ctxPicture.fill();
            if( x<10 || x>225)  dx=-dx;
            if( y<10 || y>160)  dy=-dy;
            x+=dx;
            y+=dy;
          }
        setInterval(draw,60); 

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <canvas id="frame" width=380 height=315></canvas>
        <canvas id="picture" width=243 height=182></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the solution here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/611648/Applying-a-Custom-Mask-on-an-Image-using-Raphael

The main handicap is that img url/atts  are passed as data-param to the "canvas" element, which is a bad accessibility concern, because image is treated as a shape filling. It's pros, accepts SVG styles and filters, and even works in IE8++!!

Unfortunately, a login is required in order to download the code, but FB/G+ connect will do the job quickly!